# What is the equivelant of the parameter (end=) in r?

Tags: python, r

```
for j in range(len(sudoku_board[0])):
        if j % 3 == 0 and j != 0:
            print(" | ", end="")
        if j == 8:
            print(sudoku_board[i][j])
        else:
            print(str(sudoku_board[i [j])+" ", end="")
```

Lets say I would like to translate this to r from python, what would the equivalent to the (end=) operator be?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like python `print()`'s `end` argument in r's `print` function. You can use [`cat`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cat) rather than `print` if you don't want the newlines.